# Elemento buscador en el menu de wordpress plantilla dpr bruno

Tags: wordpress, buscador

Hola estoy intentando implementar el buscador con la plantilla de visual composer dpr bruno, el caso es que en las plantillas predefinidas de wordpress es sencillo colocar el botón de buscar, pero en dpr no usa un elemento nav, usa divs, y no encuentro ningún plugin que me permita insertar el buscador en el menú, un saludo espero vuestra respuestas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Introduce este código en el div donde quieras colocarlo:

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```